# GWT displaying decimals in a textbox

Tags: java, gwt

I'm totally new to GWT so please forgive me if this is an obvious problem.

I have a TextBox from which I want to take a value and round to 3 decimal places and then return the rounded value to the same textbox.  This may not be the graceful way but it seems like this should work.

```
inputValueBox = new TextBox();
            .
            .
            .     
double doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(inputValueBox.getText());
doubleValue = (Math.round(doubleValue * 1000))/1000;
inputValueBox.setText(Double.toString(doubleValue));
```

I have attempted do to this a number of different ways, the end result is that, in the inputValueBox, all values to the right of the decimal point are reported as zero. So when I take:

(Math.round(0.99283425 * 1000))/1000 I expect to get 0.993.  What I end up with is 0.0

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Always look for existing number/date formatting libraries. GWT does provide it's own: [NumberFormat](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/NumberFormat.html).

In your own code you're seeing `0`, which is the expected result of integer division: `Math.round` returns an integral result. To force the floating point result that you're expecting, you can cast one of the operands, or simply use a float as the divisor:

```
doubleValue = Math.round(doubleValue * 1000) / 1000.0;
```